# Extracting double-digit months and days from a Python date

Tags: python, datetime, iso

Is there a way to extract month and day using isoformats? Lets assume today's date is March 8, 2013.

```
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> d.month
3
>>> d.day
8
```

I want:

```
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> d.month
03
>>> d.day
08
```

I can do this by writing if statements and concatenating a leading 0 in case the day or month is a single digit but was wondering whether there was an automatic way of generating what I want.

Comment: `d.strftime('%m')` and `d.strftime('%d')` This has got to be a duplicate.

Comment: It is a dupe -- But I must say that this one is more clear than the dupe.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Look at the types of those properties:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: d = datetime.date.today()

In [3]: type(d.month)
Out[3]: <type 'int'>

In [4]: type(d.day)
Out[4]: <type 'int'>
```

Both are integers. So there is no *automatic* way to do what you want. So in the narrow sense, the answer to your question is **no**.

If you want leading zeroes, you'll have to format them one way or another. 
For that you have several options:

```
In [5]: '{:02d}'.format(d.month)
Out[5]: '03'

In [6]: '%02d' % d.month
Out[6]: '03'

In [7]: d.strftime('%m')
Out[7]: '03'

In [8]: f'{d.month:02d}'
Out[8]: '03'
```

Comment: Thank you. For those using multiple values with manual numbering, just make sure to add the number before ":02d", e.g.: {0}/{1:02d}-{2:02d}_{3}.json'.format(othervalue, currentMonth, currentDay, othervalue2)

Comment: Just to add another formatting method to get a padded zero string you could use the `zfill()` function like so: `str(d.month).zfill(2)`

Comment: date ='2019-09-15' 
f'0{pd.to_datetime(date).month}'

Comment: this one `f'{d.month:02d}'` is perfect. Thx !

Answer (score 58):

you can use a string formatter to pad any integer with zeros.  It acts just like C's `printf`.

```
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> '%02d' % d.month
'03'
```

**Updated for py36:**  Use f-strings!  For general `int`s you can use the `d` formatter and explicitly tell it to pad with zeros:

```
 >>> d = datetime.date.today()
 >>> f"{d.month:02d}"
 '07'
```

But `datetime`s are special and come with special formatters that are already zero padded:

```
 >>> f"{d:%d}"  # the day
 '01'
 >>> f"{d:%m}"  # the month
 '07'
```

Comment: instead of a bloated textbook page this answer actually gives you a working one liner, kudos