# django concatenate filter model

Tags: django, date, model

why this is not working? I can't concatenate the filter with another variable?

I have a feeling that I'm being very dumb.

I'm new at django and trying a couple of things with the model.

When I use: **birthdate__contains='-03-'** works fine, but with the variable, nothing shows up at the url

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Employee
from datetime import datetime

```
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    mes_atual = '-'+str(currentMonth)+'-'
    employees = Employee.objects.filter(
                                    birthdate__contains=mes_atual
    )
    context = {
        'employees' : employees
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you can always use print for debugging the code

Comment: I was using on a separate file, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `datetime.now().month` will be `3` not `03`

To filter you need the date like `03`.

```
currentMonth = datetime.now()
mes_atual = '-' + str(currentMonth.strftime('%m')) + '-'
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509345/extracting-double-digit-months-and-days-from-a-python-date) for info

Your code will be:

```
def index(request):
    #currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    #mes_atual = '-'+str(currentMonth)+'-'
    currentMonth = datetime.now()
    mes_atual = '-' + str(currentMonth.strftime('%m')) + '-'

    employees = Employee.objects.filter(
                                    birthdate__contains=mes_atual
    )
    context = {
        'employees' : employees
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```